# Parenthesize the param to make sure that block will be associated with method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

```
class User
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

Running rubocop I get the following warning:

> Parenthesize the param `-> { where(active: true) }` to make sure that
>   the block will be associated with the `->` method call.

I have no slightest clue, what my `scope` definition has to do with this warning. Do you?

How do I fix the warning except for turning the check off because it makes no sense at the moment?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It wants you to do this:

```
scope :active, (-> { where(active: true) })
```

Better to turn off the warning :)

This stabby lambda syntax is perfectly fine. Maybe you have old rubocop version?

**Update:** fixed in 0.49.0.

Comment: Nope, I have the newest version (from April the 3rd - 0.48.1). Will accept in 8 mins :)

Comment: Fix is [already merged](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pull/4237) in rubocop master, check the new version soon :)

Comment: How can I turn off this warning? What should I put in .rubocop.yml to fix this?

Comment: Weird, still getting this with 0.48.1, going to disable the cop

Comment: @tirdadc: yep, 0.48.1 still has it. You need a newer version. Or master.

Answer (score 4):

`gem update rubocop` worked for me.

Comment: this is the correct answer, as far as I am concerned